# How to check in Javascript alert is present on browser and then accept it?

Tags: karate

In my application, if session of one user already exists, and the same user tries to create new session via new browser window then a Javascript alert is displayed to warn the user.
Now, this alert is displayed only if the session already exists, so I have to accept it and continue login.
Is there any method available in karate core to handle this scenario?
I am aware of dialog(true) method to handle such alerts but, here I need to check explicitly if alert is present and then handle it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: see if any of these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+dialog

Comment: @PeterThomas, Did not find any reference to check if the alert exists or not and then handle it, in those search results. Kind of stuck now.

Comment: the only way that I can help you is if you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test - but please see `optional()` in the docs